# In android 8.0 and 7.0 devices, WebView downloads index.php instead of pdf file

Tags: java, android, webview

My app has a `WebView`. While downloading `pdf file` from a `url` that contains **.pdf** extension, it works fine. But the `url` that doesn't contain **.pdf** extension - downloads index.php file in android 8.0 device but works fine in `android 6.0` and below.

For example below link contains pdf file:

http://mohfw.gov.bd/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=13010&lang=en

and you can check my `webview` in below github link:

https://github.com/ZubayerDeveloper/DocSites-v17/blob/DocSites11/app/src/main/java/zubayer/docsites/Browser.java

Comment: Does the link you provided correctly specifies `Content-Type: application/pdf`. Do you want to download & display the PDF or just download? In the latter case I would not use a WebView but instead use the DownloadManager.

Comment: No idea about that, but  just downloading pdf is enough for me right now.